# asp.net popup div with buttons no firing VB code behind, just javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code in ASP.net / VB.
When a button is pressed on the page, the div_yes_no (see code below) popsup as a YesNO message. The popup shows two buttons (YES and NO)

```
<div id="div_yes_no" class="messagepopup" runat="server">
            <br/>
            <span class="desc">Are you sure you want to transfer this data (Y/N) ?</span>
            <br/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnYES" runat="server" Text="Yes" OnClientClick="ShowCoverNONE(''); Hide2();" OnClick="btnYES_Click"  CssClass="STD_button" /> 
            <asp:Button ID="btnNO" runat="server" Text="No" OnClientClick="ShowCoverNONE(''); Hide2();" CssClass="STD_button" />          
        </div>
```

This is the code in VB which should run when btnYES is clicked:

```
    Protected Sub btnYES_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
        MsgBox("hello")
        .... actual code
   End Sub
```

The problem is that the btnYES_Click code is not firing, just the javascript fires: OnClientClick="ShowCoverNONE(''); Hide2();"

Any ideas what's missing and or how to do this a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the MsgBox("hello") in ASP.NET as you use it in windows forms application. Can you try by removing it?

Comment: sorry, I am aware of the msgbox in a "live" web site, but when testing it works. it's just there for me to see if the code runs....but it doesn't. I've removed it anyway but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net with VB.NET as Code-behind usualy does not use the OnClick attribute on Buttons. Instead you need to add the **Handles-clause** with the button's name in your VB.Net Code-behind code. Like this:

```
Protected Sub btnYES_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnYES.Click
        MsgBox("hello")
        .... actual code
End Sub
```

Please also look at this page: [How to use OnClick and OnClientClick events to Prevent Double Clicking on your ASP.Net Buttons](https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/quick-tip-how-to-use-onclick-and-onclientclick-events-to-prevent-double-clicking-on-your-asp-net-buttons/).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I do have other VB on the same page, without the Handles cause and it works (I took it out as it caused double clicking).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the answer to this problem. For others in case they encounter the same, the problem was that the code

```
asp:Button ID="btnYES" runat="server" Text="Yes" OnClientClick="ShowCoverNONE(''); Hide2();" OnClick="btnYES_Click"  CssClass="STD_button" />
```

was NOT within the Ajax ContentTemplate/updatepanel:

```
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Once I put it there, it all worked as normal.